Image of the closed unit ball is weak* dense
I'm aware that there are a few posts about this question here, but none of the proofs make the last step of this argument make any sense to me.
Here is the problem statement:  Let $X$ be Banach and $\kappa: X \hookrightarrow X^{**}$ the canonical embedding.  Let $B$ be the norm-closed unit ball in $X$ and $C$ the norm-closed unit ball in $X^{**}$.  Prove that $\kappa(B)$ is weak* dense in $C$.
I follow every step of this argument, and get stuck at the very last part.  Here is my proof:
Suppose for contradiction that $\kappa(B)$ isn't $w^{*}$ dense in $C$.  Then there exists a $w^{*}$-open set $U \subset C$ such  that $\kappa(B) \cap U = \emptyset$.  Now, the $w^{*}$-topology is locally convex so we may assume that $U$ is convex, and moreover the image $\kappa(B)$ is convex by convexity of $B$ and linearity of $\kappa$.  Hence, there exists some $\Psi \in (X^{**}_{\omega})^{*} = \kappa_{*}(X^{*}) \subset X^{***}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that: $$\Re \Psi(\tau) < t \leq \Re \Psi(\varphi)$$ for all $\tau \in U$ and $\varphi \in \kappa(B)$.  However then $\Psi = \kappa_{*}(\psi)$ for some $\psi \in X^{*}$ and each $\varphi \in \kappa(B)$ is of the form $\varphi = \kappa(x)$ for $x \in B$ so we yield: $$\Re \: \kappa_{*}(\psi)(\tau) < t \leq \Re \: \kappa_{*}(\psi)(\kappa(x)) \iff \Re \: \tau(\psi) < t \leq \Re \: \psi(x) \: \: \forall \tau \in U, \: \: x \in B.$$  In particular for $x=0$ we then conclude: $$\Re \tau(\psi) < 0 \: \: \forall \tau \in U$$ where $U$ is convex.
I'm totally lost on how this proof ends, and most arguments online seems to differ just enough in either notation or versions of the separation theorems to confuse me.  It seems like $U$ being convex should make the above equation false, giving the contradiction, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Where does this come from? This argument works to prove that $\kappa(X)$ is dense in $X^{**}$, but not to prove that $B$ is dense in $C$. For starters, $C$ contains no w$^*$-open subset.

@MartinArgerami This is from an old comprehensive exam from my university.  I am studying to take the exam soon, and this was one of the study problems.  Is there an error in the problem statement?

In particular, In Pederson's analysis now book, there is an exact question like this, but instead of the w* topology on X**, its the weak topology induced from X*, which is a weaker statement (unless X is reflexive so its the same), which has been causing me some confusion.

The statement is true, it is usually called Goldstine Theorem. But the proof cannot work as stated, because it doesn't use that $B$ is a ball, and it says that $C$ contains a w$^*$-open set, which it doesn't. Hence my question where the argument is coming from.

I posted a possible solution to this problem @MartinArgerami.  Does my reasoning check out?

On a quick look, I cannot follow the second part of your argument. Where do you use that $|\psi|\leq1$? Because what you are trying to prove is false for $|\psi|>1$, and I cannot see where you use this fact.

Perhaps this may solve the problem.
Suppose for contradiction that $\kappa(B)$ isn't $w^{*}$-dense in $C$.  Then there exists $\psi \in C \setminus \kappa(B)$ and a basic open set: $$V(\psi,F, \epsilon) = \bigcap_{k=1}^m \{\varphi \in X^{**} \: | \: |\kappa_{*}(\eta_k)(\psi - \varphi)| < \epsilon\} = \bigcap_{k=1}^m \{\varphi \in X^{**} \: | \: |\psi(\eta_k) - \varphi(\eta_k)| < \epsilon\}$$ such that $V(\psi,F,\epsilon) \cap \kappa(B) = \emptyset$.  Now, $\kappa(B)$ is convex by linearity of $\kappa$ and $V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$ is open.  We also have that $V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$ is convex.  Indeed, if $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $\varphi_1,\varphi_2 \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$, observe that for $1 \leq k \leq m$: $$|(\lambda \varphi_1 + (1-\lambda)\varphi_2)(\eta_k) - \psi(\eta_k)| = |(\lambda \varphi_1 + (1-\lambda)\varphi_2)(\eta_k) - (\lambda \psi + (1-\lambda)\psi)(\eta_k)|$$ $$\leq \lambda | \varphi_1(\eta_k) - \psi(\eta_k)| + (1-\lambda) |\varphi_2(\eta_k) - \psi(\eta_k)| \leq \lambda \epsilon + (1-\lambda)\epsilon = \epsilon.$$  Hence by the Hahn Banach separation theorem, there exists $\kappa_{*}(\tau) \in (X^{**}_{\text{weak}})^{*} = \kappa_{*}(X^{*})$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that: $$\Re \: \kappa_{*}(\tau)(\varphi) < t \leq \Re \: \kappa_{*}(\tau)(\kappa(x)) \: \: \forall \varphi \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon), \: x \in B$$ $$\iff \Re \: \varphi(\tau) < t \leq \Re \: \tau(x) \: \: \forall \varphi \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon), \: x \in B.$$ In particular then we have $\Re \varphi(\tau) < 0 \: \: \forall \varphi \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$.  Now, if $\tau \neq \eta_k$ for any $1 \leq k \leq m$, then we can simply chose $\varphi \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$ with $\Re \varphi(\tau) > 0$ so it must be the case that $\tau = \eta_j$ for some $1 \leq j \leq m$.  However, I claim that we may chose $\tau \neq \eta_k$ for any $1 \leq k \leq m$.  Indeed, if this wasn't possible, then for all $\kappa_{*}(\alpha) \notin \{\kappa_{*}(\eta_k) \: | \: 1 \leq k \leq m\}$ and every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\varphi \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$ and $x \in B$ such that: $$\Re \: \varphi(\tau) \geq t > \Re \: \alpha(x).$$  In particular given $\kappa_{*}(\alpha) \neq \kappa_{*}(\eta_k)$ for any $1 \leq k \leq m$, take $t = \inf_{y \in B} \alpha(y) \in \mathbb{R}$ since $\lVert \alpha \rVert < \infty$.  Then we would have some $\varphi \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$ and $x \in B$ such that: $$\Re \varphi(\alpha) \geq \inf_{y \in B} \Re \alpha(y) > \Re \alpha(x)$$ which is nonsense.  Hence, such a choice for $\tau$ is possible, implying that we may assume $\tau \neq \eta_k$ for any $1 \leq k \leq m$.  However then by Hahn Banach we may simply chose $\varphi \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$ with $\Re \varphi(\tau) = 1$, which contradicts $\Re \varphi(\tau) < 0$ for all $\varphi \in V(\psi,F,\epsilon)$.  Thus, it must be the case that $\kappa(B)$ is infact $w^{*}$-dense in $C$.
